# Do I have to modify device tree?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

I've started to study Linux recently and been tried to manipulate GPIO. However, there are a lot of ways to do that. So, I'm having trouble understanding how to do it.

When manipulating GPIO by GPIO API, is it essential to modify the device tree..? And if it is, what is the role of the device tree..?

(I've tried to manipulate GPIO for a week and I still couldn't find the answer. In addition, if you don't mind can you suggest a list of books that can help me understand these concepts?)

What I know is there are generally three ways to control GPIO.

1. Using the sysfs interface.
2. Using GPIO API.
3. Using mmap().

I'm trying to use the second method.

Comment: Is it essential to modify the device tree when manipulating GPIO by its API? No. Role of device tree? The device tree is basically a data structure used by the Linux kernel to describe the hardware configuration, including the GPIO pins.

Comment: "*What I know is ... 3. Using mmap()*" -- Where or how did you acquire such "*knowledge*"? Using mmap() to modify registers owned/managed by a driver is not conducive to a stable kernel.

Comment: "*What I know is ...*" -- You didn't even mention the preferred/proper method of using GPIO, which is through a kernel driver (rather than any userspace hack). Study **Documentation/driver-api/gpio/using-gpio.rst** and **drivers-on-gpio.rst** in the Linux kernel source. `The userspace ABI is intended for one-off deployments. ... Do not under any circumstances abuse the GPIO userspace ABI to cut corners in any product development projects.`

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Now I can manipulate GPIO! I've figured out that using the device tree is an easy way to configure pins including GPIO and understood that using mmap() is inappropriate.